# Does the targeted class of a criteria query require references to objects its being filtered by?

Tags: hibernate, class, object

When writing a criteria query targeted at some class B that's filtered by some class A does B require a `ManyToOne` relationship to be explicit? Doing so would create a bidirectional relationship between A and B.. which doesn't feel right to me because B doesn't necessarily care about A.

The goal of this query is to get all Bs by some A and then filter Bs further by some of its own properties.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question.  What version of hibernate? Java?  Did you try something already?  If so, post your code.  If not, be clear that you don't really even know how to begin.

Comment: I'm just asking a general question

Comment: To reiterate, when I conceptualize A and B objects, B shouldnt have an explicit relationship to A so giving it one feels like a code smell. On the other hand, it seems like the query is a lot easier to write when that relationship is present

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something with something that does not exist, meaning you can't reference a non-existing entity property in a query.

But you can apply filters in either direction in uni-directional associations:

`select b from A a join a.bs b where a.something = something and b.something ...`